# is there something wrong of iOS simulator's 'color offscreen-rendered' function?

Tags: ios, render, simulator

i want to see which view is offscreen-rendered in my app.So i use the  iOS simulator's  'color offscreen-rendered' function,it can color those offscreen-rendered view by yellow color.But after the app launched,the whole screen is colored by yellow and i don't believe it.

Then i try my test code like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    //    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    //    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [self.window makeKeyWindow];
}
```

As you can see above,i simply set the window's rootViewController three times different by orginal controllers: 'UITabBarController','UINavigationController' and 'UIViewController'.

Guess what?

Only the 'UIViewController' is not whole screen colored!!!

[image]

So anyOne knows why the orginal rootViewController and  UINavigationController will occur the whole screen offscreen-render??????

Answer (score 3):

It's because default `translucent` value of `UITabBar` and `UINavigationBar` are `YES`.

You should check Apple documents for [UINavigationBar.translucent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624928-translucent) and [UITabBar.translucent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623458-translucent) for more information.

A small demo by creating a `UINavigationController` with a red background root view controller, we can compare the difference when `translucent` is `YES` and `NO`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  UIViewController* viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
//  nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
  self.window.rootViewController = nav;

  [self.window makeKeyWindow];
  return YES;
}
```

**By default, translucent is YES**. So you can see background of `UINavigationBar` has a little red.

[image]

Color offscreen-rendered

[image]

**But when we set translucent to NO**. No more red in background of `UINavigationBar`.

[image]

Color offscreen-rendered

[image]

---

We have transparent here so that's why screen is colored. You can try similar thing with `translucent` of `UITabBar`.

To avoid offscreen-rendered with `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`, you should set this property to `NO`.